# Oracle, Execute immediate Insert

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to insert random generating data into table, here's code"

```
begin
  FOR x in 1..300 LOOP
    Execute immediate 'insert into emp values ('||prac_seq.nextval||','''||'name'||x||''','||trunc(dbms_random.value(1,300))||');';
  end loop;
/
```

table `emp` has 3 columns - `id`,`name`,`idmgr`;

above query in execute immediate statement looks like:

```
insert into emp values (13,'name25',193);
```

This block did not run. When I tried to run single execute immediate statement (f.e.

```
begin
  Execute immediate 'insert into emp values ('||prac_seq.nextval||','''||'name23'','||trunc(dbms_random.value(1,300))||');'
end;
    /
```

ORA gives me an error:

> Execute immediate 'insert into emp values
>   ('||prac_seq.nextval||','''||'name23'','||trunc(dbms_random.value(1,300))||');';
>   end; Error report: ORA-00911: invalid character ORA-06512: at line 3
>   00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
>   *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
>              letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
>              character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
>              any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
>              (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
>              delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
>              Reference Manual.
>   *Action:

And why? Commas, quotes.. everything is checked and fine.

Comment: There is no need for using native dynamic SQL(`execute immediate`) in this case at all - use static SQL.

Comment: Before immediate I use JUSt 2000 insert into statements. It takes... a lot of time. With dynamic SQL - 7.54 sec! So yes - there is need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove `;` from your dynamic query.

Comment: Stupid... I was so focused on this commas that i missed it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using execute immediate for this. Try connect by level.

```
select prac_seq.nextval, 'name'||level, trunc(dbms_random.value(1,300)) as rnd
from dual
connect by level <= 300;
```

Comment: Nice one. Thanks! But still - why there's an error?